# Set default value for "max width" of "includegraphics"

Tags: graphics, adjustbox

I'd like to set a default value for `max width` (and `max height`) for `\includegraphics` elements.

I have `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` in the preamble so images have the `max width` key. Then I tried to set the default value like this:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{max width=\textwidth,max height=0.5\textheight,keepaspectratio}
```

But it's like it's not there. Applying it directly to the `\includegraphics` element like `\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth,max height=0.5\textheight,keepaspectratio]{...}` works.

Comment: `Gin` keys consider only `graphicx` options, for example `width=...` or `height=...` etc.

Comment: @Zarko but if you use `export`, the `\adjbox@fam` is set to `Gin`, so the keys provided by `adjustbox` are in the `Gin` key family (else you'd get an error because those keys wouldn't be defined).

Comment: my claims are based on my experiences. so far i didn't manage that `Gin` consider `adjustbox` option. i'm glad to hear, that i'm wrong.

Comment: @Zarko I just learnt that from viewing the sources. Still for some reasons the setting of `adjustbox` options outside of `\includegraphics` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why not just defining your own new command for it `\newcommand\myimage[2][]{\includegraphics[max width=\textwidth,max height=0.5\textheight,keepaspectratio,#1]{#2}}` and then use `\myimage{imagefilename}` or `\myimage[extra options]{imagefilename}` instead in your document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## New Answer

Instead of redefining `\includegraphics` one could use `etoolbox` and `\patchcmd`. This might be a cleaner solution.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname Gin@ii\endcsname
  {\setkeys {Gin}{#1}}
  {%
    \setkeys {Gin}
      {max width=\textwidth,max height=.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio,#1}%
  }
  {}{}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{./chapterinsection.pdf}
\end{document}
```

---

## Original Answer

An ugly solution, redefining `\includegraphics` to include those two keys by default:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\includegraphicsBAK\includegraphics
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\MyStarProcessor[1]
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {\def\ProcessedArgument{*}}
      {\def\ProcessedArgument{}}%
  }
\RenewDocumentCommand \includegraphics { >{\MyStarProcessor}s O{} o m }
  {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
      {%
        \includegraphicsBAK#1
          [%
            max width=\textwidth,
            max height=.5\textheight,
            keepaspectratio,
            #2
          ]
          {#4}%
      }
      {%
        \includegraphicsBAK#1[#2][#3]{#4}%
      }
  }

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{./chapterinsection.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice patch for `Gin`! +1