# Table with images and wrapped text

Tags: tables, graphics

I am trying to build the table of two columns. The first one contains an image and the second one pretty long description. Moreover, the size of the table exceeds one page, therefore my idea was to use *longtable* package. 
Here is my code:

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|} \hline
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Thesis/figures/ALICE.jpg}} & \parbox[t]{10cm}{\centering \textbf{ALICE} is designed to study heavy-ions collisions. It is mostly focusing on study of the quark-gluon plasma. \strut}  \\\hline   \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Thesis/figures/Alpha.jpg}} & \parbox[t]{10cm}{ \textbf{ALPHA} is working on trapped antihidrogen atoms. The precise measurement of hydrogen and antihydrogen may allows to understand the fundamental symmetries between matter and antimatter. \strut}  \\\hline
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{Thesis/figures/AMS.jpeg}} & \parbox[t]{10cm}{ \textbf{AMS} is a particle detector that looks for dark matter, antimatter and missing matter. It is attached to the International Space Station. \strut}  \\\hline

\end{longtable}
```

And here is the result: 
[image]

How can I improve the layout of my table?

Comment: Whatever you are using to achieve the double spacing effect, can you turn it off, at least for captions?  If your thesis is required to be double spaced, ask them why?

Answer (score 1):

do you like to have white space around image?

[image]

with help of the package `adjustwidth` you can move baseline of image on its center and also add vertical space above and below of image. for shorter code is used keys `Gin` which use Skillmon's hack given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439918/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, longtable}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
    \expandafter\patchcmd\csname Gin@ii\endcsname   % needed etoolbox
      {\setkeys {Gin}{#1}}
      {\setkeys {Gin}
          {width=\linewidth,                     % standard graphicx settings
           valign=c, margin=-3pt 6pt 0pt 6pt,#1}     % settings from adjustbox
      }
      {}{}
\begin{longtable}{|p{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.33\arrayrulewidth}|
                   m{\dimexpr0.6\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.33\arrayrulewidth}|
                }
    \hline
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    & \textbf{ALICE} is designed to study heavy-ions collisions. It is mostly focusing on study of the quark-gluon plasma.            \\
    \hline
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    & \textbf{ALPHA} is working on trapped antihidrogen atoms. The precise measurement of hydrogen and antihydrogen may allows to understand the fundamental symmetries between matter and antimatter.                      \\
    \hline
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    & \textbf{AMS} is a particle detector that looks for dark matter, antimatter and missing matter. It is attached to the International Space Station   \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is implemented as a paragraph of `\fbox`es.  `\lineskip` is used to overlap the edges of the boxes.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent{\fboxsep=0pt 
\lineskip=-\fboxrule
\fbox{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}}\vrule
  \hspace{\tabcolsep}\parbox{6cm}{\textbf{ALICE} is designed to study heavy-ions collisions. 
    It is mostly focusing on study of the quark-gluon plasma.}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
\fbox{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}}\vrule
  \hspace{\tabcolsep}\parbox{6cm}{\textbf{ALPHA} is working on trapped antihidrogen atoms. 
    The precise measurement of hydrogen and antihydrogen may allows to understand the fundamental 
    symmetries between matter and antimatter.}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
\fbox{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-c}}\vrule
  \hspace{\tabcolsep}\parbox{6cm}{\textbf{AMS} is a particle detector that looks for dark matter, 
    antimatter and missing matter. It is attached to the International Space Station.}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
\par}% needed to use current lineskip
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how can I split this table into two columns?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  It was originally a two column tabular.  If you wanted a gap in between, you can add that with @{\hspace{\columnsep}}.  At 12cm+ it is already too wide for one column.