# Picture and tabular

Tags: tables, floats, diagrams

I would like to insert a picture in a table just like this (made with word)  :
[image]

In LateX I wrote this :

```
\begin{tabular}{|m{8cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|}\hline
Représentation sur la droite & Encadrement & Intervalle \\ \hline
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=1cm]{intervalle1.png} & b & c \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
```

But I have this

[image]

The picture hides the table. I tried

```
\includegraphics[scale =0.5]{intervalle1.png}
```

But I have the same result.

Is anybody could help me please ? I tried many thing in tabularx or tabulary but I have got the same problem.

Thanks for having reading me,

Taltos,

Comment: @schtandard This _question_ is not a duplicate of the referred _question_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible solution, which does not require additional packages, is to add last `p`-column of zero width, where you set a zero-width rule with the same height as the graphic *plus* the height of a `\strut`. LaTeX always set a `\strut` in rows. You then force the row to have a height corresponding to the height of your graphic *plus* equal white space above and below it. The command `\ht\strutbox` sets the height of a `\strut`.

The `@{}`s remove the `\tabcolsep`s LaTeX automatically sets at each side of a column. I also added the line `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}` to avoid the collision between the `\hline` and the ascender of the letters in cells. You may increase the value if you prefer more space.

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document delete option "demo" 

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt} <- avoid collision between cell content and \hline
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|m{8cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.5cm}|@{}p{0pt}@{}}\hline
    Représentation sur la droite    & Encadrement   & Intervalle &   \\ \hline
    \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=1cm]{intervalle1.png} 
    & b             & c &\vphantom{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr(0.5cm+\ht\strutbox)}}             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much ! It works ! I'll study how you did it with vphantom and co !

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document delete option "demo" 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|S{m{8cm}}|S{m{2.5cm}}|S{m{2.5cm}}|}\hline
Représentation sur la droite    & Encadrement   & Intervalle    \\ \hline
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=1cm]{intervalle1.png} 
                                & b             & c             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}               % <---
\setcellgapes{3pt}                  % <---
\usepackage[export,demo]{adjustbox} % <---
                                    % in real document delete option "demo" 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
Représentation sur la droite    & Encadrement   & Intervalle    \\ 
    \hline
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=1cm,valign=c]{intervalle1.png} 
                                & b             & c             \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same.

**Edit:**
one more way how to include image in table. In case that table contain many image with the same width it may be handy to use `Gin` keys for settings image parameters. With use of `adjustbox`˙and `etoolbox` for patching `GIN` and considering [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439918/%20set-default-value-for-max-width-of-includegraphics/439927#439927) a solution can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export,demo]{adjustbox} % in real document delete option "demo"
    \usepackage{etoolbox}           % <---

    \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[!ht]
        \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \expandafter\patchcmd\csname Gin@ii\endcsname   % needed etoolbox
      {\setkeys {Gin}{#1}}
      {\setkeys {Gin}
        {width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep,      % standard graphicx settings
         valign=c, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt,#1}       % settings from adjustbox
      }
      {}{}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
Représentation sur la droite    & Encadrement   & Intervalle    \\
    \hline%
\includegraphics{intervalle1}
                                & b             & c             \\
    \hline%
\includegraphics{intervalle2}
                                & d             & e             \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This uses TikZ, for short tables only and some manual adjusts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=3.5]
\tikzset{interval/.pic={
\foreach \i in {-1.5,-1,...,1.5}
\draw[gray] (\i,0)--+(-90:.15);
\draw[-stealth] (-1.8,0)--(2,0);
\draw[cyan,very thick] 
(-.5,0) node[scale=1.4]{$[$} node[below=2.4mm,black]{$a$}--
(1,0)   node[scale=1.4]{$]$} node[below=1.5mm,black]{$b$};
}}
\def\c{1.3} % control the 1st column
\def\r{1}   % distance of 2 rows
\draw[shift={(-.5,.4)}]
(0,0) rectangle (1,-\r-1.2) 
(0,0) rectangle (2,-\r-1.2)
(-\c-.2,0) rectangle (0,-\r-1.2)
(0,-.8)--+(0:2)--+(180:\c+.2);
\path
(0,0)      node{Inequality Symbol}
--+(0,-\r) node{$\mathbf{a\leq x \leq b}$}
(1,0)      node{Interval Symbol}
--+(0,-\r) node{$\mathbf{x \in [a;b]}$}
(-\c,0)    node{Representation on the line}
--+(0,-\r) pic{interval};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```