Can I change the default settings for \begin{figure}?
When I type \begin{figure}, it is automatically filled to the following:
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

Is it possible to change this (and other automatically filled pieces of code) to another default? For example like this:
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}

I am now addding the float and width options manually for every figure, but I wonder if there is a way to automate this.
Thanks in advance!

For float placements you can change the macro \fps@<type>, so to change figure you can use \renewcommand\fps@figure{H}. For \includegraphics, take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439918/set-default-value-for-max-width-of-includegraphics/439927#439927

As an aside, you might want to change your habbits to use \caption{Caption\label{fig:enter-label}} instead of putting \label after the \caption command (the latter might lead to inconsistent spacing in some edge cases).

"it is automatically filled to the following" This sounds like something your editor would do, but you don't tell us which editor you use.

(also are you sure that using [H] by default is a good idea? This will lead to awful results as you don't allow latex to properly position the figures.)

Welcome to TeX.SE! Which editor do you use? WinEdt, TeXStudio etc.?

Thanks for the fast replies! I will check how the document turns out when using [H], if it looks bad I will remove it. I am working in OverLeaf, is that what you mean with the editor?

Overleaf is the editor, it does not support customisations like this, see Is it possible to add new predictions/autofill in Overleaf?

Your question is just about overleaf as the completion is unrelated to tex which only sees the expanded text. I don't think you can add more text fragments in overleaf. Defaulting H is certainly not ideal as it means you are adding a float and disabling it by default, it would be simpler not to add the float at all.
